# How to connect development mode rails app with nginx server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, rubygems

I want to run my rails app in development mode with nginx server as I want to override remotipart. Please guide me how to connect rails app with nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install nginx
2. Install Passenger
3. Set nginx.conf file according to you
4. Start nginx  Go through localhost your nginx page will start
5. gem install passenger in your project
6. passenger-install-nginx-module
7. passenger start

For more details got through this link: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu